# Is my camping stove leaking? How can I check?

Tags: cooking, gear-care, canister-stoves

I have a Campingaz Camping 206 S camping stove, like the following picture, though I'm hoping any advice I get here will apply equally well to any kind of small gas camping stove.

[image: Campingaz Camping 206 S Stove]

It's been a pretty reliable companion for heating up tins of soup or beans when I'm camping. I've started finding, though, that when I arrive on site and start trying to cook with it, I find that the burner doesn't get particularly hot - after it's been heating my mess tin on full blast for a good few minutes, the tin is still cool enough to touch, even on the bottom.

After turning it off and shaking it a little bit, I can still hear a little butane sloshing around in the canister, but after removing the canister and inserting a spare, it starts working reliably again and heats my next meal up properly. I go home afterwards, store it in a cupboard, but then find that the issue occurs again the next time I take it out a few months later.

I'm guessing that I might have a very slow leak or something, but the stove doesn't smell at all - certainly not how it smells when I actually open the valve. Is there a better way for me to check? Might I just be using it wrong?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146040/discussion-on-question-by-ymbirtt-is-my-camping-stove-leaking-how-can-i-check); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: People if you have an answer post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if your stove has a leak if you weigh it, together with the gas canister. Record the weight before long-term storage; check when you want to use it again.

The particular scenario (having a flame but it's not hot) is very strange. My best guess is, your gas canister contains a mixture of gases (e.g. propane + butane); the "best" gas (e.g. propane) leaks out, while the "bad" gas (e.g. butane) remains. Butane should still provide a very hot flame, but maybe its flow rate is too low on your highest throttle setting.

Comment: The usual CampingGaz cylinders are just butane, so if using it in cold conditions that alone could be the answer to the slow burning

Answer (score 2):

These burners take containers such as this one:

[image: A gas container]

They are holed when inserted into the burner and have no own valve that allows removing and closing them. I suspect that the sealing between the stove and the cylinder is not 100% tight, causing the leak if the thing is not used for some time.

Looking at cylinders from other vendors, they seem to all have a separate valve on them, probably just to avoid this problem.